# Algorithm for determining if a particular image would be smaller as a PNG or JPG

Tags: image-processing, imagemagick

I am writing a script to optimize a bunch of images. I want to determine which format to convert the image in — PNG or JPG. Goal is small file size without compromising on quality.

Is there an algorithmic way of determining this? I can convert into both, compare sizes, and discard the bigger one, but I was wondering if there is a way to determine it based on number of colors, etc.

Comment: I presume you are aware that JPEG files cannot contain any transparency information so if you convert from PNG files with transparency you may lose that... and also that JPEG files are 8-bit whereas PNG files can contain 16, or even 32 bits per pixel, so you may lose colour resolution and introduce banding effects if you go to JPEG.

Answer (score 0):

You can tell the size of a converted file without writing it to disk like this:

```
convert -size 1000x1000! xc:gray +noise random JPEG: | wc -c
1742282

convert -size 1000x1000! xc:gray +noise random PNG: | wc -c
6010785
```

Obviously you may want to set the quality factors and colour depth and other parameters to tune the space, but this will tell you the size. For example, you may want to specify the maximum JPEG size:

```
convert -size 1000x1000! xc:gray +noise random -define jpeg:extent=300k JPEG: | wc -c
286103
```